# Error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when I try to launch my Node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = fastify();

try {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notes_db');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}

app.get('/', (request, reply) => {
    try{
        reply.send("Olá mundo");
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})

app.listen(5000, (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(`Server running on ${address}`);
});
```

When I run the command `npm start` or `node index.js` this error is shown to me:

```
(node:10332) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(node:10332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\notes-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:299:13)
    at parseHandler (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\notes-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:130:14)
    at QueryReqWrap.callback (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\notes-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:114:7)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:205:10)
(node:10332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10332) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the 
future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My server is running but I want to know how to fix this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try specifying the `useNewUrlParser` option like this:

```
try {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notes_db', { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

### Edit

Since you're trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas cluster and not local installation, replace the connection URI to the one you get on Atlas.

Here is a tutorial I found: https://medium.com/@sergio13prez/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-d1381f184369

Comment: Didnt work, same error happened again ```(node:12844) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(node:12844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\notes-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:299:13)
    at parseHandler (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\notes-server\node_modules...```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same code you show? Because the change would've gotten rid at least of the warning. Also, since you have a `trycatch` around the connection part, it wouldn't throw an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: Yes, here is it https://prnt.sc/wwpgkj and my code https://prnt.sc/wwpkgs

Comment: The error is different this time, in the screenshot. Do you have mongodb running locally?

Comment: Im trying to run on MongoDB Atlas, but i dont know how can i connect Cluster in my file index.js. Im reading this tutorial https://medium.com/swlh/fullstack-crud-application-with-fastify-mongoose-and-react-admin-86d3e743dcdf So i'm using same mongoose connect like this tutorial

Comment: Ok, that explains it. `localhost:27017` means mongodb would be installed locally. If you want to connect to Mongo Atlas, you need to change the URI to the one you get from there.

Comment: Sure, where can i get the URI? I cant find it

Comment: Check my edited answer ^. Don't forget to whitelist your IP